# Best way to make multiple background images?

Tags: css, background

I want to have different background images for different subpages (i.e. "Menu" has a image #1, "Contact us" has image #2 etc.)

I have the following css code:

```
html {
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

}

But this sets **one** image to every subpage. Now I can make each subpage have a different div in the html (e.g. div id="menubg"; div id="contactusbg") and add the above CSS (slightly changed) for each div, but then I create a ton of unnecessary CSS items.

So, is there a better way to do it?

- Should I put the background image into the HTML directly and add one css to that image? Is that doable with the preservation of all CSS properties like "cover"? (Ideally I would like to have a code for the image in in each HTML and one CSS for all subpages, can I do that?)
- Is using JavaScript (or other) a good/better soultion?
- Is making multiple CSS styles the only solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I normally do this is to give the `body` the background, not the html.  You will want to give your body an id name of the page it's on.

First of all, you want to blanket all of your body elements as well as putting all of your extra `background` information into their own lines:

```
body {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

then, if you want img1 on `menu` and img2 on `contact us`, give your `body` and ID of one of the two:

```
<body id="menu">
```

then in your CSS you just write in your `background-image` property by itself:

```
body#menu {
    background-image: url(images/bg1.jpg);
}
```

and the same with your contact us page:

```
<body id="contact-us">
```

-

```
body#contact-us {
    background-image: url(images/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

So your CSS file ends up looking like this:

```
body {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
body#menu {
    background-image: url(images/bg1.jpg);
}
body#contact-us {
    background-image: url(images/bg2.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, but then the image doesn't resize itself, or I have to repeat the whole CSS block of the body, that is, the css body#menu looks like this:  
**body#menu {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;  
    -webkit-background-size: cover;  
    -moz-background-size: cover;  
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;**
**}**  
  
What I'm trying to do is to reduce the amount of repetition, can I do it? Does it even make a difference? ***I'm sorry for the formating but it seems I can't make a linebreak***

Comment: @baki, the first body line in the css will take care of the background fixed and size cover. The other two body lines only need the background image. This makes all body elements have the size and position, then each individual body element just needs to specify the image only.  When I get on a computer, I can explain better. Phones aren't great for this!

Comment: Hmmm it doesn't work for me. I think I'm missing something even though the code looks quite simple (tested in chrome and IE). The background does not resize. Is the body#menu supposed to contain only the image with additional rules?

Comment: @baki, I'm finally at a computer: sorry for the delay.  I've updated the final code in the end to show you what you should have on each style element.  Have you made sure that you've given your `<body>` an ID?  for example: `<body id="menu">`

Comment: Sadly it still doesn't work, I've tried quite a few combinations. It only works when each id has all the specifications (of cover and cover fixes for different browsers). Guess I'll just use that, it's not that bad after all, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @baki That's very strange, if you're still interested, post more of your html and I can take a closer look.

Comment: Well my html consists basically of <body id="menu"></body> (+the rest necessary stuff). So I really don't have a clue why it doesn't work. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/zLtd2obu/  (you can't switch the pages but you can still see that the second img does not reduce its size without "cover")

Comment: Well it does not work for me :p Try adding background-size: cover; to the #page1 background and see if whether the image changes its size.

Comment: @baki, Sorry I wasted your time earlier!  I've taken a look again and the problem is that because you have `background` dictating your image, size, position and attachment, it overrides any other `background-` changes.  If you want to do any extra background fixes, you have to specify every one of them or specify everything you need in one `background` line.  Here's another fiddle - I hope this is it: http://jsfiddle.net/zLtd2obu/3/

Comment: No problem :) Thanks again, now it works. I've incidentally came across another solution. By using abstract classes, but your solution does almost the same thing, its simpler and in my particular where I only use 1 background per page, its better.